# 'file_contents()' doesn't return type GLchar

Tags: file, opengl

I'm following [*An intro to modern OpenGL*](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2.2:-Shaders.html), which is written in C. However, I'm writing in C++.

I've reached chapter 2.2 and cannot get further because of this line of code:

```
GLchar * source = file_contents(filename, &length);
```

Compiling this returns "Cannot assign 'void' to 'GLchar *'" (I might be paraphrasing)

I looked for the "file_contents" function in "file_util.c" and the only function labelled "file_contents" is a 'void' function that does not return anything.

Comment: What do you mean it's just a "void function?" Does it take `void` for the parameters? That's generally what that would mean.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `file_contents`? Ideally, you'd create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can better understand your problem.

Comment: Additionally, if your tutorial is available online, you should add a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

Just typecast it. In C `void*` pointers implicitly typecast to every other pointer type. In C++ you must be explicit about it.

```
GLchar * source = (GLchar*)file_contents(filename, &length);
```

Comment: this just gives me the "Void* cannot be converted into GLchar*" error.

Comment: @user3391187: It's a function returning a void pointer and an explicit cast between pointer types *must* be allowed. But maybe your C++ compiler needs some convincing. Usually you'd use that for class instances, but it may help you either. `GLchar *source = static_cast<GLchar*>( file_contents(…) );` If that doesn't work as well, you've got some severe other problem with your program or build setup.